# C# Transparent Window stops displaying controls if application runs for a long time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

There is an issue with my application that I am trying to resolve. I'm having difficulty reproducing this as I am lost as to what may be the issue and have not been successful in debugging.

**Application:**
My application is a tray application (MVVM). Here are the steps of its execution.

1. App Start
2. Main Window (Transparent Created, ResizeMode=NoResize, ShowInTaskbar=False, topmost=true)
3. Event Occurs
4. ViewModel Created
5. ViewModel added to ObservableCollection
6. NotifyPropertyChanged informs Main Window to update its stack panel
7. Stack Panel displays the ViewModel as a View (inherits from DockPanel)
8. Timer Elapsed
9. ViewModel removed from ObservableCollection

**Problem:**
This application will work properly, displaying notifications when desired. However, after running for a long period of time (sometimes days or weeks), it 'may' stop working in that no notifications will be displayed.

**Investigation:**

- What I've found from the logs is that all the steps I've mentioned in
  above(1-9) are working (no exceptions, seems to be successful, values are correct).
- You can try to minimize and then maximize or try to bring to front
  the window through playing in the task manager. However, that does not resolve the problem.
- Have tried closing all applications then triggering the event. Notification will not show. Restarted the application, notification will still not show.
- Restarting the application does not resolve the issue. However, if you log off and log on, that will resolve the issue.

I tried to provide as much information as I can, if you need more I could try to provide it. I'm lost as to what else I can do to debug the issue.

**Additional Information:**

- Using MetroWindow from MahApps to create the MainWindow.
- Timer is from System.Timers
- When you arrive to the state where the notification doesn't show, you can run the application as debug (in visual studio) and it still won't work. I stepped through the code and everything seems alright.

Comment: What type of resources are you using? And also, what type of timer are you using. Is it possible at some point it could have been disposed and it's no longer firing? And something I cannot get from your title and description; on which window are you displaying the controls? Is the transparent window updating another one?

Comment: If restarting the app doesn't fix the problem then you are off the hook, it is not your problem.  Finding the *other* apps that take their unfair share of the desktop heap, the ones that get terminated when you log-off, that's work that nobody here can do for you.  Make sure that it is somebody else's work and that they care enough.

Comment: The only helpful thing to do is add some sort of **logging** to your application.  Log every Event with date & time so you can see when exactly it's stopping to work. That will help you find out what happens before that. You may be able to reproduce this then.